# Barplot in R fill with certain values

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset which contains the data of pairs playing a game. I have a barplot that shows the total games played by the pairs. But now I want those bars('number') to be filled with the amount of games they successfully completed('sum')[image]. I can't get it to work. The barplot is created like this:

```
barplot(height = game_count$number, xlab = 'Pairs', ylim = c(0,35), ylab='Games played')
```

The data looks like this:

```
             participants sum number
1    06104873220647518670  30     32
2    06105747340637377404  23     24
3    06113978630633565020  28     32
4    06121794480617858550  25     27
5    06122613960611857952  23     26
6    06123139380653583516  25     28
7    06123650620648276595  28     32
8    06124453210624910109  32     34
9    06127993700610846968  24     26
10   06128440030639764541  19     24
11   06132461300624244572  26     30
12   06137611390651588167  25     28
13   06145014400637290807  16     19
14   06163181050611257617  30     30
15   06172024240651919112  21     23
```

Comment: `barplot(height = game_count$sum, xlab = 'Pairs', ylim = c(0,35), ylab='Games played')`

Comment: Where is `Freq` column? Please make sure code reproduces issue. Also, to answer, *I want those bars('number') to be filled with the amount of games they successfully completed('sum')*, why not just swap `number` (or `Freq`) for `sum`?

Comment: Oh yes I edited the question. 'Freq' should be 'number'. Well because I want to visualize the amount of games they successfully completed 'sum' relative to the total games they have played 'number' in one barplot.

Answer (score 1):

One option can be `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
game_count$Freq <- game_count$sum/game_count$number
#Plot
ggplot(game_count,aes(x=1:nrow(game_count),y=Freq))+
  geom_col(fill='cyan3',color='black')+
  xlab('')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
barplot(t(game_correct[c('number', 'sum')]), beside=TRUE, ylim=c(0,35), col=c('black', 'green'), main='Games played and successive games by the pairs', xlab='Pairs', ylab='Games')
```

Result in this graph:[image]